# How to extract ORB_SLAM features to port and work on Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I would like to port the ORB features extraction process to work on Android. Basically I wont ORBextractor.cc file to work inside RenderScript contex. The process is following

1. Camera frame is captured using Android classes.
2. Java context: Frame is stored inside a Render Script Allocation, which is set as current input allocation.
3. Render Script context: Frame is converted from YUV to RGB color space
4. Java context: Current output allocation is set to current input allocation
5. Render Script context: Frame is re sized and converted to gray
6. Here start ORB features extraction;Java context: Current output allocation is set to current input allocation
7. Render Script context: Here is Example ComputePyramid called and calculate all scale levels 8...
   ORBextractor.cc can be presented with a call tree like this:

void ORBextractor::operator()
ComputePyramid(image, mask)

- cv::resize
- cv::copyMakeBorder-     /opencv/modules/ocl/src/imgproc.cpp
                           /opencv/modules/ocl/src/opencl/imgproc_copymakeborder.cl
  ComputePyramid is called and calculate all scale levels.

Any help from where I can start or look for some exaples?